# CodeIgniter - Remove "Index" From URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, controller

> **NOTE:** I'm not talking about removing `index.php` - I mean `index` - the method name.

My current URL looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/view-topic/index/my-topic
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
wwww.mysite.com/view-topic/my-topic
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See routing in documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set up the routes for this, in `application/config/routes.php`, add a new line:

```
$route['view-topic/(:any)'] = 'view-topic/index/$1';
```

This will route your URL `http://url.com/view-topic/anythinggoeshere` will mask the `view-topic/index/anythinggoeshere` controller.

More information on routing:

- [Routing with Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Thank you my friend! Will mark your answer as best as soon as 10 minutes is up. :)

Comment: Above will call `index function` for `other functions` in `view-topic controller` too.

Comment: This is not a good long term solution. As Rohan mentioned, this will match all methods in the view-topic controller so unless this controller only uses a single method this will not scale.