# How would i create a custom dynamic url in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I hate the codeigniter custom urls where it's: domain.com/controller/action/username

How can I have it like a normal website like: domain.com/username

Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - Remove "Index" From URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734921/codeigniter-remove-index-from-url)

Comment: Something like this : `$route['controller/(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1';`

Answer (score 4):

You try this in routes.php

```
$route['(:any)']        = "controller/action/$1";
```

Here is the routing documentation : **[routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)**

Answer (score 2):

Please refer http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html. You can do this by URL routing