# CodeIgniter URI Routing: remove method name index from URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes, uri, url-routing

I am working with CodeIgniter (V:2.2.6) and I have a simple class `User` with some basic methods like `create`, `update`, `edit`, `delete` and `index`. For the `index` function, I am using an argument `$user` (which is the second URI segment) in order to display some information regarding that user. So the default URL looks like:

```
/user/index/john
```

to display some information about the user 'john'.

Now, I want to remove the term 'index' from the URL, so that it looks like:

```
/user/john
```

For that purpose I have added the following rule in routes.php.

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = "user/index/$1";
```

It serves the purpose, but it prevents accessing other functions like `/user/create` and goes inside `/user/index` automatically. To solve this problem, I can not see any other way except manually adding routing rules like

```
$route['user/create'] = "user/create";
```

for each method of the `User` class, which is not cool at all. So, please can anyone suggest me a better way of routing under the current circumstances?

Here are my codes:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function index($user = '') {
        echo "index!";
    }

    public function create() {
        echo 'create!';
    }
}
```

Note: I have gone through the CodeIgniter [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html) for URI Routing and another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734921/codeigniter-remove-index-from-url), but could not figure out a promising solution. And please don't suggest for CodeIgniter version update.

Comment: Why is it "Not Cool" to add in your specific routes for create, update etc with the (:any) being last in the list? You wont go wearing out your keyboard by typing them in.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw well I kept the function list smaller for the sake of demonstration. Consider a real life scenario where the number of methods inside a class might be 10, 20 or 30.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this is the answer you like, but i think it should work.
Just put this function in your user controller.

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index($method);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Remapping Function Calls (http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/controllers.html#remapping) definitely sounds better than adding routing rules manually.

Comment: Alright, thx for accepting - but keep in mind you should prevent the possibility to create usernames like create, update, delete, insert and index.

Comment: CI3 has this issue, or my mamp config doesn't support something, I got the same issue with the index which was working by default before on other web apps. This snippet is a must have. Thanks @sintakonte!